# LaTeX and Unicode within verbatim environment

Tags: unicode

I am really, really hoping someone has a neet trick for my problem.

I have three Unicode symbols I need to put inside my verbatim environment

```
├ ─ └
```

all others are not important to me and  most definitely will not be. I am used to LaTeX and Texmaker and would want to avoid any shifts to new versions or alternative tools whatsoever at this point. Is there someone out there that can help me with this problem?

Comment: Just a sidenote to your 'new versions and alternative tools' bit: I can't of any downside to using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. Just use `xelatex` on the command line instead of `pdflatex`. If you're using `latex | dvips | ps2pdf` because of postscript-y things, `xelatex` handles them in a single pass (in my experience).

Comment: Do you have a monospace font with those symbols?

Answer (score 8):

Just load `pmboxdraw`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
verbatim { ├ ─ └ }
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you !! it works. it may be is "just" for you bt to me this was an enormous problem . thnx once again :)

Comment: @user78516 I didn't mean it was easy: “ just” refers to the simplicity of the solution. I happened to remember one of the umpteen packages by Heiko Oberdiek.