# How to copy code chunk containing unicode character in verbatim environment?

Tags: symbols, unicode, verbatim, unicode-math, code

In Julia programming language, one can type Unicode character such as 
[image: screenshot]

If I want to copy paste a chunk of code in a tex file. What should I do?

Here is an unsuccessfule attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}

Hello world
μ
x
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

In the output, the $\mu$ does not appear:

[image]

**Edit**
Ok I did some research and found [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245777/latex-and-unicode-within-verbatim-environment)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
verbatim { ├ ─ └ }
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

However, when this is the output I get

[image]

**Edit 2**
I also tried the following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document} Hello world 
\newline μ 
\newline Hello world again 
\begin{verbatim} μ x 
\end{verbatim} 
\end{document}
```

The font "Liberation Serif" cannot be found / The font "Liberation Mono" cannot be found

Comment: The easiest is to use XeLaTeX with `fontspec` and select a font that contains Greek characters (many fonts have those), both for regular text (`\setmainfont`) and for verbatim (`\setmonofont`). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398335/xetex-typewriter-fonts-and-quotes and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228671/writing-greek-in-xelatex-with-the-default-font, I'll vote to close as a duplicate of the 2nd - note that you don't need all the `\newfontfamily` and `polyglossia` stuff.

Comment: Example with the font Liberation (for Linux), that has Greek (and several other Unicode characters) both in normal serif text and in monospace: `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
Hello world
\newline
μ
\newline
Hello world again
\begin{verbatim}
μ
x
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Marijn. I tried your code but get `The font "Liberation Serif" cannot be found / The font "Liberation Mono" cannot be found` Do you know what I should do?

Comment: This means that this particular font is not installed on your system, you can choose a different font that you do have installed. On Windows maybe Times New Roman as serif and Courier New as mono font, for example.

Comment: Many thanks for your help @Marjin. now the code works. However when trying to implement this on another 200+ pages .tex file, I get the following error message "Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your typesetting engine to ,e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of "latex" or "pdflatex". In Texstudio > User command, it is written "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex" (In order to use the `minted` package). The question is now definitely another one but do you have a idea? many thanks again!

Comment: You can also use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `--shell-escape` in order to use minted, there is probably a button for that somewhere (I'm not sure, I don't use TeXstudio) or otherwise you can change the settings in Options > Configure TeXStudio > Commands.

Comment: Ok many thanks @Marijn. I'll try to find the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing Greek in XeLaTeX with the default font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228671/writing-greek-in-xelatex-with-the-default-font)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @PhelypeOleinik. I will check this link out. but right now the main problem is using the `fontspec` package.